# Hacer que una expresión regular en Python solo acepte ciertas combinaciones

Tags: python, regex, diccionarios

Tengo esta expresión regular:
"GT[AC][GT]AC"
Quiero hacer un programa donde Python me busque esta expresión en una secuencia dada, pero no quiero que me busque todas las posibilidades. O sea, quiero que busque "GTATAC" y "GTCGAC", pero no "GTAGAC" o "GTCTAC". ¿Hay alguna forma de hacerlo?
Si sirve de algo, la expresión regular está dentro de un diccionario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que sólo admita una de dos posibilidades, debes usar el operador "or" (`|`) y no una lista de caracteres entre corchetes, ya que en ese caso estás multiplicando el número de posibilidades.

Una solución trivial es que tu expresión regular sea:

```
GTATAC|CTCGAC
```

No obstante, ya que ambas comienzan y terminan igual y lo único que cambia es las dos letras que tienen en medio, puedes restringir el "or" a esa zona, mediante un *non capturing group* `(?:)`. Así:

```
GT(?:AT|CG)AC
```

### Ampliación

La expresión regular anterior encaja tanto con `GTATAC` como con `CTCGAC` y en ese sentido es lo que pedías. Pero dependiendo de cómo la uses en tu programa (es decir, qué función de las muchas que tienes en el módulo [re](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)), podrás usarla para ver la primera aparición de esa cadena, o todas, o en qué posición aparece cada una, etc.

Creo que lo que necesitas sería `re.finditer()` que encuentra todas las apariciones del patrón dentro de una cadena dada y te retorna un iterador sobre el que puedes iterar en un `for`, devolviéndote en cada iteración un objeto de tipo "Match", que contiene información sobre qué subcadena fue encontrada, en qué posición dentro de la cadena, etc.

Ejemplo:

```
import re

dna = "GTAGCGAGTATACTCGTCGACCAGGTGAGTCGACCGAGCAGTGAGTAGCAGGGGTATACCAGTAGTAGTACAGCAG"
patron = "GT(?:AT|CG)AC"

resultados = re.finditer(patron, dna)
for m in resultados:
  print("Fragmento comienza en {}: {}".format(
    m.start(), m.group(0)))
```

Resultado:

```
Fragmento comienza en 7: GTATAC
Fragmento comienza en 15: GTCGAC
Fragmento comienza en 28: GTCGAC
Fragmento comienza en 53: GTATAC
```

Comment: ¿Si uso estas opciones, seguiría buscando ambas expresiones? Porque el fin último del programa es buscar dichas expresiones en unsa secuencia y que me diga la posición donde empiezan. Si solo va a buscar una de las dos, no me sirve.

Comment: @Bea Pues lo tienes tan fácil como probar tú misma si con ese cambio ya te va. Pero todo depende de cómo siga tu programa. He ampliado la respuesta para mostrarte un ejemplo.

Comment: Creo que no puedo usar la función .finditer (por especificaciones del ejercicio), pero creo que puedo hacerlo igual con .search

Comment: @Bea Efectivamente, `pattern.search()` te busca la primera aparición dentro de una cadena, a partir de una posición que le indiques en el parámetro `pos` (0 por defecto), y te retorna un Match, en el que puedes consultar su campo .start() para descubrir el índice donde lo encontró. Puedes volver a llamar a pattern.search() con la misma cadena y otra `pos` de inicio (la anteriormente encontrada más uno) para que busque la siguiente aparición, y repetir el esquema dentro de un bucle